# Convert CSV to SQLite when your don't know how many columns there are

Tags: python, sqlite, csv

The code below works for a test program I am currently working on because I know how many columns are in the csv file and what the headers are. I am trying to figure out how to modify the code to take any csv file without knowing how many columns there are and still convert it to a sqlite database. I understand that pandas can do it very simply but I am trying to learn another route. Thank you.

```
import sqlite3, csv

con = sqlite3.connect("person.db")
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE person (memberNum STR,lastName STR,firstName 
STR,streetAddress STR, city STR, state STR,zipCode STR,phone 
STR,favoriteStore STR,dateJoined STR, duesPaid STR, PRIMARY KEY(memberNum))""")

with open('Members.csv','r') as person_table:
    dr = csv.DictReader(person_table, delimiter=',') # comma is default delimiter
    to_db = [(i['Member #'], i['Last Name'], i['First Name'], i['Street Address'], i['City'], i['State'], i['Zip Code'], i['Phone'], i['Favorite Store'], i['Date Joined'], i['Dues Paid']) for i in dr]

cur.executemany("INSERT INTO person VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);", to_db)
con.commit()

#Select statment to query the db
cursor = con.execute("Select * from person order by lastName")
for row in cursor:
   print "ID = ", row[0]
   print "Last Name = ", row[1]
   print "First Name = ", row[2]
   print "Phone Number = ", row[7], "\n"
```

Comment: In database design *without knowing how many columns there* is not an ideal approach to building tables. Databases are not spreadsheets even for file-level DBMS's like SQLite or MS Access. Scripts should not be adjusting schemas on the fly. Design your structure, add/manipulate data from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the column names *before* executing the `CREATE TABLE` command in SQLite. Then construct the `CREATE TABLE` statement and execute it. Make sure you order the dictionary keys the same way in both the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements or you are liable to put a value in the wrong column.